# Storing bank account in vCard file

Tags: vcf-vcard

Question from the title - is it possible to store bank account number in vCard? Does the specification says something? Any guidelines?

m.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. vCARD supports extensions, which means you could use something like

```
X-BANK-ACCOUNT-NUMBER:12345678
```

Or, you could just put the details in the comments field.

You can [read more about the vCARD extensions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this topic.  That said, I strongly recommend against storing any sensitive information in a vCard.  As far as I know, vCard does not support encryption (someone please correct me if I am mistaken).

Comment: Denso Wave advertises that their SQRC® can store private information, too, but it requires a specific scanner and I do not know whether these devices understand vCard.